Installing pgBouncer for postgres 14
Please note: I'm still learning a lot of things about postgres. I'm asking for advice to install pgBouncer, but if you have any better suggestions what I could do, please tell me.
I have a nodejs application on a single vps which uses pg-promise for interacting with a postgres db. pg-promise uses pg-pool so connection pooling is done on the application level.
I'm planning to add a second vps to scale my application horizontally. I want to implement connection pooling on the database level by using pgBouncer.
I'm installing pgBouncer on top of my Postgres 14 db on my vps, following the instructions on their website.
Currently, I have a database with 2 users:

"admin", which has admin access to the database
"user1", which can only read, update, write, and delete data in tables, but it cannot do other stuff (like deleting tables)

My SQL to setup this db and the users looks like this (simplified):
CREATE ROLE "admin" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'myadminpassword' SUPERUSER;
CREATE DATABASE "mydb" WITH OWNER "admin";
CREATE ROLE "user1" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'myuserpassword';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "mydb" TO "user1";

I then connect to the db "mydb" with "admin" and run the following SQL:
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM "user1";
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO "user1";
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "user1";
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO "user1";
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO "user1";

Now, in the authlist.txt file from pgBouncer, I have to add a user and an md5-hash of the password of the user of the postgres db. And I'm not sure which user I have to add. I use the "admin" user when I'm managing the database (I connect to the db using pgAdmin) like adding or deleting tables, columns, ..., but my application uses the "user1" user. Which user should I add to pgBouncer (I'm guessing "user1").
Second question: is my connection string (postgres://user1:myuserpassword@:5432/mydb) still the same? Or do I need to use another connection string to connect to pgBouncer?
Thanks in advance!
Edit: please note that my postgresql server is a separate vps than the vps which is running the nodejs application. I'm planning to install pgBouncer on the postgresql vps.
Edit 2: I installed pgBouncer with the help of the docs and this tutorial. I HAVE NOT TESTED IT YET!
/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini:
[databases]
mydb host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb

[pgbouncer]
...
pool_mode = transaction
max_client_conn = 1000
auth_type = hba
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/pb_hba.conf
admin_users = admin
...

/etc/pgbouncer/pb_hba.conf
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 scram-sha-256
host all all ::1/128 scram-sha-256
host all all <nodejs-vps-ip>/32 scram-sha-256

I've added my application vps ip to the allowed ip's in pgBouncer's pb_hba.conf file so only this vps can connect to it.
Edit 3:
I got it working, my pg_hba.conf file for pgbouncer looks like this:
host all all <application-vps-ip>/32 scram-sha-256
local all all scram-sha-256

I added the necessary credentials to userlist.txt

How did you configure pgBouncer?

please see my updated answer

You say you have followed a tutorial, but your configuration file says you didn't;  it specifies a different authentication type than the one you seem to want to use. Perhaps you want to follow the tutorial more closely.

@mustaccio I'm also checking the docs and I decided to go with hba auth. I got it working now.
